# Is `Marshall.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate()` required?

Tags: c#, delegates, marshalling, ffi

I want to pass a callback from C# to native rust code. Online I saw those two methods:

1. Directly passing in a function that conforms delegate type.

```cs
Api.set_on_new_connection(OnNewConnection);

// ffi
[DllImport]
public static extern Result set_on_new_connection(OnNewConnection callback);
```

2. Create an instance of delegate, marshal it, and pass the pointer:

```cs
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(new OnNewConnection(OnNewConnection));
Api.set_on_new_connection(ptr);

// ffi
[DllImport]
public static extern Result set_on_new_connection(Intptr callback);
```

The first method seems to be working just fine, and I can call this function from native DLL. Is there perhaps more to this, and should I be using the Marsall class?

I am using .Net 5 or newer.

Comment: Correct, generally no need unless you are doing custom marshalling, say deep within a struct. Side point: You need to hold on to the delegate object, either store it in a field, or store in a local and use `GC.KeepAlive`

Comment: Ah okay, I guess that refers only to method 2 right?

Comment: Generally no need to use `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`, you can pass the delegate directly. If the callback is called *after* the return of `set_on_new_connection` then you need to keep the delagate alive, this applies to both methods